# NLog: When Nlog Send mail the all message

Tags: nlog

i read this article for nlog mail setting from here http://blog.marko-kastelec.com/2015/10/28/nlog-tutorial/.

```xml
<target name="mailbuffer" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" slidingTimeout="false" bufferSize="100" flushTimeout="-1">
  <target name="mail" 
          xsi:type="Mail"
          smtpServer="my.smtp.server.com"
          smtpPort="port"
          smtpUserName="user.name"
          smtpPassword="password"
          subject="${machinename} - My subject string (${shortdate:format=dd. MM. yyyy})"
          from="address.to.send.from@mail.com"
          to="address.to.send.to@mail.com"
          layout="${longdate}   LEVEL=${uppercase:${level}},   LOCATION=${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=true:methodName=true},               
                  MESSAGE=${message}${newline} EXCEPTION=${exception:format=tostring,StackTrace}${newline}" />
</target>
```

1) my question is when mail will be send by nlog ?

2) can we control the mail sending activity? say i want to invoke some function of nlog and all logged entries will be mailed instead of automatic mail sending and entries will be flushed from memory?

if it is possible then please guide me what and how to customize it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) my question is when mail will be send by nlog ?

This fully dependents on your config. Some possibilities:

### For every log message

e.g. every Warn, Error and Fatal message:

```xml
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="mail" />
</rules>
```

### Log messages grouped

Group multiple messages in one mail. Same rule, but also replace the target. E.g.
Send a mail when there are 20 error messages, or 10 minutes after the last error.

```xml
<target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="mailLog1" slidingTimeout="true" bufferSize="20" flushTimeout="600000">
      <target xsi:type="Mail" name="mail" ../>


</target>
```

and write to `mailLog1`, e.g.

```xml
<rules>
  <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="mailLog1" />
</rules>
```

### Limit the messages

Send message for each event, max 5 messages per 10 minutes.

```xml
<target name='limiting' type='LimitingWrapper' messagelimit='5' interval='0:10:00'>
 <target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail"
            ...   

    />
</target>
...

<rules>
  <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="limiting" />
</rules>
```

#### Buffer, but send when there is a error

Buffer all messsages and send when there is an error:

```xml
<target name="file" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Error">
  <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" ..>
    <target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail"


    />
  </target>
</target>
```

> 2) can we control the mail sending activity? say i want to invoke some function of nlog and all logged entries will be mailed instead of automatic mail sending and entries will be flushed from memory?

See examples. You can also combine all wrapper targets with other targets or other wrapper targets. See the [documentation for the possible (wrapper) targets](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Targets).

Comment: you said `Send a mail when there are 10 error messages, or 10 minutes after the last error.` what setting is there which inform nlog
to there is 10 error message ? bufferSize="10" means 10 error message or any kind of 10 messge including debug,warn, 
exception & error etc

what is the meaning of flushTimeout="60000" ? 60000 is milisec or sec ? does it mean flush error from memory after 60 sec ?
please answer my question. thanks

Comment: yes the buffersize. I have improved the example.The 20 are the one you send to the target, in the `<rules>`

Comment: for what settings mail will send `10 minutes after the last error.` nothing as such i found in your answer. please point that where you set 10 minute?

Comment: what is the meaning of flushTimeout="60000" ? 60000 is milisec or sec ? does it mean flush error from memory after 60 sec ? please answer my question. thanks

Comment: Mili. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target. Fixed the example.